# Status of POSIX implementations

Tags: c, posix

I just found out that the `getline()` function which is originally a GNU extension is now part of the POSIX 2008 standard.

Is there some overview of how broadly is this version of POSIX supported?

Comment: +1 for taking the time to question what's portable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just go ahead and use it. It's possible to implement `getline` (but not the more powerful `getdelim`) as a very fast/efficient wrapper around `fgets`, so if you're willing to do that as a fallback, using `getline` doesn't really make your program any less portable. (Versus something like using `__fpending`, which cannot be implemented portably and requires an implementation-specific hack to emulate.)

Also, of course, both `getline` and `getdelim` can simply be implemented on top of `flockfile`/`funlockfile` and `fgetc`. It's not very efficient, but it will work anywhere.

Comment: `getdelim` and `getline` can also be implemented on top of `fscanf` with the `%200[^x]` conversion specifier, where `x` is replaced with the delimiter character you want to stop at and 200 with the amount of buffer space you have. (You can use `snprintf` with `%%%zu[^%c]` to generate this conversion specifier.)